# Any arc joining $a$ and $b$ is continuum which is irreducible between $a$ and $b$

Tags: general-topology

A Continuum is a compact connected Hausdorff space. We say that a continuum $K$ is irreducible about a subset $A$ of $X$ provided that $A \subset K$ and no proper subcontinuum of $K$ contains $A$.

***We need to prove any arc joining $a$ and $b$ is continuum which is irreducible between $a$ and $b$***.

Comment: "Prove that any arc is whatever" could be construed as "Pick any arc you choose and prove that it is whatever", but I don't think that is what is meant here. It could also mean prove that if you pick any arc at all, then no matter which one it is, then it is whatever." The latter could be unambiguously phrase as "Prove that every arc is whatever", and that's how I would write it.

Comment: In arcwise connected,that is there is a homeomorphism from $I$ into $K \subset R$ such that f(0)= a and f(1)= b  the function f is called arc

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $F$ is a proper subcontinuum that contains $\{a,b\}$, and $c\notin \operatorname{arc}([a,b])$. Then $F = F_1 \cup F_2 :=  (F\cap \operatorname{arc}([a,c))) \cup(F\cap \operatorname{arc}((c,b]))$. Now surely $\operatorname{cl}_{\operatorname{arc}([a,b])} F_1 \subset \operatorname{arc}([a,c])$ which doesn't intersect $\operatorname{arc}((c,b])$ which contains $F_2$? So $\operatorname{cl}_{\operatorname{arc}([a,b])} F_1 \cap F_2 = \varnothing$. Likewise we have $\operatorname{cl}_{\operatorname{arc}([a,b])} F_2 \cap F_1 = \varnothing$.

Quoting from Wikipedia:

> $X$ is connected if $X$ cannot be written as the union of two nonempty separated sets (sets for which each is disjoint from the other's closure).